# Taking video of a person whilst on their property

Tags: privacy

Can a person stand on your property and take videos of you inside your home without permission then show that recording to others?

Comment: Please specify where you are. Answers might depend on that.

Comment: Has the person been told to stay off the property? What activities did they capture on the video that they're showing to others?

Comment: I am inside my house and without my permission a person (neighbour came to my house through a closed gate and began taking videos of me inside my house - through a closed side window. He then went around the back, again through a closed gate and began banging on my rea windows. When he refused to go away I told him vehemently to "go away" - he then showed the video to everyone and even passes by (U.K.) I took videos and cctv of his aggressive behaviour - this was passed to the local council and they told the neighbour I had a watertight case against him